# Android DHCP enabled disabled check

Tags: android, dhcp

I wanted to know if there is any way to check programmatically in android phone whether DHCP is enabled or disabled. (Assuming its possible to disable DHCP through some way or dhcpd is not running)

Comment: Just to be sure, are you talking about the DHCP server `dhcpd` or the client `dhcpcd` ? Also, can you expose what you're trying to do, there is maybe another way ?

Comment: I am just trying to show whether current user has static ip setup or is using dhcp.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to know if Android is currently using static IP adresses or DHCP attributed ones :

```
try {
     if ( Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), 
           Settings.System.WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP) == 0 )
         /* Static ip addresses mode is not enabled */
     ;
     } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        /* Do something smart here */
     }
```

However, note that this method seems now deprecated and that it does not work across all devices (AVD for example).

Comment: and i think it would not be that accurate for showing whether dhcp is enabled or not.

Comment: I dont't think either. This is the only method I've managed to find though.